# Should we combine a value of an attribute A with values of other attributes B, C, ... to make A unique?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a relational database schema as follows

[image: schema]

The primary keys are underlined.

The scenario is I have to manage the bookings for the tennis courts. As you can see from the image, each court belongs to exactly one sport center, each center belongs to exactly one city. Let's *forget the staff, player, and booking table* because my question does not concern them.

So my professor had a very weird way of implementing this schema in MySQL. He made the `CenterName` and `CourtName` (and even `PlayerName`) unique attributes. `CityName` is also unique but I think it's justified. What is worth questioning is the way he did it:

Suppose that I have `City A` which has `Center 1` which has `Court i`. He would store `City A_Center 1` in the `CenterName` field and `City A_Center 1_Court i` in the `CourtName` field.

Basically he would chain information from other attributes to make an attribute unique, instead of defining unique conditions on the attribute sets `(CenterName, CityID)` and `(CourtName, CenterID)`.

The way he justified for his design is that he could use the names instead of the ID numbers when he call stored functions. He also said names should be preferred over IDs, and ID should only be used for filtering (not sure what that is). He said the combining technique above to make names unique "is done all the time in practice". I really doubt that.

Is that true?

Comment: Lets say John Smith is a üöayers name, how many Jphn smith are the in GeaterNew York thousands. even combined are almost never unique. Numbers have a fixed size and consist of 8 bytes(BigINZ( try to find 8 Bytes as character for unique names, that still can be read

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: The information you seem to give about columns--but who knows because you don't give a full legend for that diagrarm--does not imply what your instructor has said but if what's not included is not prevented then it doesn't contradict them adding further specification. You need to ask them what the full specification is. After all, this is likely an example of certain design notion, not necessarily reflecting the real world. They also might be naming things specifically to let you see how data agrees with declared constraints & or a value is in the right place. Please also give DDL & DML. [mre]

Comment: Re lack of clarity here & why should give a [mre] like you are required to in code questions: It's not clear what you mean by "He made the CenterName and CourtName (and even PlayerName) unique attributes." Did they declare them UNIQUE or are you just talking about the example data? "He would store City A_Center 1 in the CenterName field and City A_Center 1_Court i in the CourtName field." So what? That doesn't violate constraints given. Maybe they are just giving names whose correct location in the DB is clear. It's not clear what exactly is being done that you call "the combining technique".

Comment: Can I ask the vintage of your professor, and how long since he was "in practice"? What you're alleging sounds like a caricature of pre-Relational schema designs -- specifically a hierarchical model. There's a good reason businesses use Identifiers, even if Names are unique. In your example, though, there's plenty of Cities called 'Springfield'; and I would guess plenty of Sports Centres with a 'Court 1'; and I would guess plenty of Players named 'John Smith' or 'Bob Jones'.

Comment: For all I know there are two different Sports Centres in two different Springfields each named 'Springfield Sports Centre', each with a 'Court 1' and each with a Player 'John Smith'; and those two 'John Smiths' have made a court booking on the same day at the same time.